# Solve the following complex equation

Tags: calculus

We need all complex numbers satisfying the following equation:

$z^4+4z^3+7z^2+6z+3=0$

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: We do? Didn't know that...

Answer (score 4):

HINT: factor the equation: $$z^4+4z^3+7z^2+6z+3=(z^2+az+b)(z^2+cz+d)=0$$
And then, determine what the coefficients  $a, b, c, d$ must be to satisfy the equation.

Then: use the quadratic formula on each factor.

Comment: Please note, you should always feel free to roll back on any edits I make, or add to them, and I won't feel bad. +